# Who calls the On<something> methods in the Winforms controls?

Tags: winforms, winapi, events

I'm interested in the architecture of the Winforms. One of the things that I'm trying to understand is the event handling. On the one side we have a bunch of protected `On`-methods (`OnPaint`, `OnMouseDown`, etc) in the `Control` class. On the other side we have a `WndProc` function. But what is in the middle? Who actually calls these protected methods?

Comment: Based on window message received through `WndProc` Control class itself calls those methods.

Comment: The WinForms framework maps windows messages to events

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The majority start out as a Windows message, either posted to the message queue with PostMessage (like WM_KEYDOWN => OnKeyDown, WM_LBUTTONDOWN => OnMouseDown) or sent directly to the window procedure with SendMessage (like WM_ACTIVATE => OnActivate, WM_SHOWWINDOW => OnLoad).

These messages are dispatched when the Application.Run() message loop calls GetMessage() and processed by Control.WndProc().  Which basically contains a large switch-statement on Message.Msg.  A class derived from Control has its own WndProc() override to handle messages that are specific to the native Windows control they wrap.  Like TreeView, TVN_SELCHANGING => OnBeforeSelect.

Then there are some that are synthesized by Winforms itself.  From your code assigning a property like AutoSize => OnAutoSizeChanged, BackColor => OnBackColorChanged, Parent => OnParentChanged.  The kind of properties that can have side effects on other controls.

And a few that are synthetic from state that Winforms builds on top of normal Windows messages, OnEnter, OnLeave, OnValidating, OnLayout fit that category.

There's a great deal of code involved with this, but this is the rough outline of it.